# Exclude Part of Video/Image OpenCV Object Recognition/Tracking

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition, hsv, video-tracking

I am trying to track a basketball through a short clip using OpenCV. I am using code to help me try to find the correct upper and lower bounds for the color code, but the ball is of very similar color to the game clock near the bottom of the video. How can I cut this off in my object tracking code, so that the program does not simply track the clock? I am using code from this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/

The code where I think this change would be made is in the following block:

```
    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the ball
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    center = None
    # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if radius > 10:
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

I know I haven't provided a MWE but I'm not sure how to do that in this case. I think my question is at least straightforward, if not simple.

Comment: Instead of using the largest contour (cf. `c = max(...)`), get the `n` largest contours, for each get the `center` as already present, and discard that one, which seems to be the clock (the `center`'s `y` would be approximately the image height, since you state, it's near the bottom). Is the camera "view" static, or does the camera move?

Comment: If the camera doesn't move then you can simply apply the approach you are using but by just adding a filter to diff the frames so that you only work with objects that are moving. This diff basically should work as a mask for your original image. If the camera is almost moving then you might have to adapt some other technique like finding features that are only present in, say, clock and filtering out based on that.

Comment: @HansHirse unfortunately the camera is moving, the clips all look similar to the following link: https://youtu.be/mhy9ow6et-I?t=235  There are a lot of moving objects so this may cause some trouble.